# How to install Signal on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, cache

Whenever I try to install Signal on my Ubuntu, I get the following cache error message:

<Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list ([option] not assignment)>

How to proceed?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do have?

Comment: Your post mention the word Xenial, however it is already past EOL.

Comment: So, what is the content of "entry 1" in named file?? Please edit your question and add contents.

Comment: @Liso The PPA for signal uses the word Xenial. It works on newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186 Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1374510/edit) and add the content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list` in the question. This will tell us what is wrong.